# How to dump only lists with flow_style with PyYaml or Ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have the following content:

```py
data = {"values": list(range(3)),'some_key': {'value': 2, 'unit': 'm'}}
```

When I dump this dict to YAML using `default_flow_style=True` I got the following content:

```
>>> print(yaml.dump( data, default_flow_style=False))
some_key:
  unit: m
  value: 2
values:
- 0
- 1
- 2

>>> print(yaml.dump( data, default_flow_style=True))
{some_key: {unit: m, value: 2}, values: [0, 1, 2]}

>>> print(yaml.dump( data, default_flow_style=None))
some_key: {unit: m, value: 2}
values: [0, 1, 2]
```

I would like to dump this dict keep the `values` with flow_style (like when executing with `default_flow_style=None` and `default_flow_style=True` but keeping the behavior of `some_key` exactly as when using `default_flow_style=False`.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Using PyYAML 5.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot achieve that goal using PyYAML without changing the representer that is part of the dumper.

In ruamel.yaml you can mark a node for dumping in flow mode, and everything "below" that will then be dumped as flow-mode as well (it has to be):

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def flist(x):
    retval = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq(x)
    retval.fa.set_flow_style()  # fa -> format attribute
    return retval

data = {"values": flist(range(3)),'some_key': {'value': 2, 'unit': 'm'}}

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
values: [0, 1, 2]
some_key:
  value: 2
  unit: m
```

You get the `values` key first, because it is first in the definition of `data` (assuming you are using an up-to-date Python 3)